# React HOC : render hijacking with functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, stateless, purely-functional

From [this blog article](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e), the rendering of a component can be altered this way:

```
function iiHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  return class Enhancer extends WrappedComponent {
    render() {
      const elementsTree = super.render()
      let newProps = {};
      if (elementsTree && elementsTree.type === 'input') {
        newProps = {value: 'may the force be with you'}
      }
      const props = Object.assign({}, elementsTree.props, newProps)
      const newElementsTree = React.cloneElement(elementsTree, props, elementsTree.props.children)
      return newElementsTree
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to work only if the passed components is itself a class component.

How would one go about writing the same code so that it works on functional components ?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can just pass the props from the wrapper directly to the functional component like so:

```
const jediEnhancer = (FunctionalComponentToWrap) => {
  return class jediEnhancer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        forceIsWithUser: false 
      };

      this.awakenTheForce = this.awakenTheForce.bind(this);

    awakenTheForce(){
      this.setState({forceIsWithUser: true});
    }

    render(){
      return <FunctionalComponentToWrap awakenTheForce={this.awakenTheForce} {...this.props} />
    }
  }
}
```